# Python argparse static arguments

Tags: python, argparse, command-line-interface

I'm new with argparse in python.

My program can reset create, delete or reset the password of an account.

```
python manager.py create  <some_username>       # Create a account
                  delete  <some_username>       # Delete a account
                  resetpw <some_username> mysql # Reset mysql pw of account
                  resetpw <some_username> unix  # Reset unix pw of account
```

The arguments "create", "delete", "mysql" and "unix" are static. How can i implement that in argparse?

I've tried as following:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='manager')
parser.add_argument('create', action='store_true', help='Create a account')
parser.add_argument('delete', action='store_true', help='Delete a account')
args = parser.parse_args()
```

But this doesn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by 'static'?  It's not a normal Python concept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for [subparsers](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argparse.ArgumentParser.add_subparsers):

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(prog='manager')
sub = parser.add_subparsers(dest='command')
sub.add_parser('create', help='Create a account')
sub.add_parser('delete', help='Delete a account')

print parser.parse_args(['create'])
# Namespace(command='create')
```

As a side note, I'd recommend you to try [plac](https://code.google.com/p/plac/) or [argh](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/argh). They provide simpler and more intuitive syntax than standard argparse